# ¿Cómo guardar valores en diferentes variables de una tabla escribiendo una única sentencia?

Tags: r, loops

Tengo que ir haciendo determinada cuenta con diferentes variables de una tabla (tabla1) e ir guardando los valores en otras variables de una segunda tabla (tabla2). Según la variable de cual se trate, será la variable en la que lo guardaré. Pero la cuenta es siempre la misma. Por lo tanto, en vez de ir escribiendo una línea por cada variable guardada, se me ocurrió hacer un `for` que lo simplifique. `tabla1` y `tabla2` son tables.

```
#suponiendo que son 8 variables:
for (i in 1:8) {
    tabla2[[colnames(tabla2)[i]]]=(tabla2[[colnames(tabla2)[i]]])*100/(tabla1[[colnames(tabla1)[i]]])
}
```

Primero que nada, aunque no sé exactamente la diferencia, creo que tengo que utilizar `[[ ]]` y no `$` (según ejemplos que pude ver en [este link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23299684/r-error-in-xed-operator-is-invalid-for-atomic-vectors) y en [este otro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33614152/using-a-variable-to-refer-to-another-variable-in-r)). Aunque reconozco que aún no entiendo muy bien qué son los "atomic vectors".

El error que me da es siempre el mismo:

> ```
> Error in tabla2[[(colnames(tabla2)[i])]] : 
>    subscript out of bounds
> ```

Entiendo que esto quiere decir como que estoy tratando de hacer algo con un elemento que no existe porque me salí de los límites/dimensiones del vector o matriz. ¿Estoy en lo correcto?

Sin embargo, no veo por qué...

```
colnames(tabla2)[1]   # sí funciona. Me da el nombre de la primera variable

colnames(tabla2)[8]   # también funciona. Me da el nombre de la última variable

tabla2[[(colnames(tabla2)[1])]]  # no funciona. 
# En este caso esperaba que me diera los valores de 
# la primera variable (columna 1 de la tabla2).
# Sin embargo, me devuelve el mismo error de arriba.
```

También he probado escribiendo la sentencia de otras formas como, por ejemplo:

```
tabla2[[simplify2array(colnames(tabla2))[i]]]
```

o

```
tabla2[[getElement(colnames(tabla2),i)]]
```

pero siempre me da el mismo error. Aunque, por ejemplo:

```
simplify2array(colnames(tabla2))[4]    #sí funciona
getElement(colnames(tabla2),4)         #sí funciona
```

Les agradezco de antemano por su tiempo y ayuda.

Comment: Hola @sebollin, creo que __antes__ de escribir __una__ sentencia, sería bueno que vayas parte por parte realizando lo que necesitas en el `for` y luego, en caso de que te funcione lo arreglas de modo para hacerlo una sentencia. Si puedieras compartir por que la idea de hacerlo una setencia, pues en mi opinión no creo que sea lo mejor, el código, si bien lo lee la máquina, es también para quien usa ese código (tu futuro yo, u otra persona) y es importante ser claro y que más que claro que cada línea con solo una acción? Finalmente intenta `?is.atomic`

Comment: Hola @jbkunst, gracias por tu comentario. Creo entender lo que dices, te paso explicar la situación y lo que estoy intentando. Tengo 2 tablas con múltiples variables y necesito hacer una operación entre ellas e ir guardando el resultado en una de esas tablas. 
En este ejemplo que planteo, son únicamente 8 variables. Pero en realidad, en cada tabla, tengo muchas más variables con las que deseo hacer la misma operación/cuenta.
Mi objetivo es conseguir una forma para no tener que escribir una línea (o más) por cada variable, siendo que es la misma operación para cada una de ellas.

Comment: @jbkunst , suponte que fueran 100 variables; además de ser mucho más engorroso, hay más probabilidades de que existan errores (de tipeo u otra cosa) en 100 líneas que en 1 sola. Además de que las variables tienen nombres totalmente distintos (no son del estilo `V1`, `V2`, `V3`, … , `V100`), por lo que esa probabilidad de error aumentaría.
Es decir, con paciencia y mucho tiempo puedo lograr el objetivo de realizar la operación en 100 o 200 líneas y guardar el resultado (que es lo principal). Pero mi idea es aprender a hacerlo de otra forma.

Comment: @jbkunst , Sobre lo que me comentabas acerca de que tal vez esto de hacerlo en una sentencia pueda ser más difícil de leer para una persona, creo que puedes tener razón. Pero en este momento no me preocuparía por eso pues mi objetivo es aprender otra cosa; además he tenido la constancia de ir comentando y explicando que estoy intentando hacer en cada sentencia.

Comment: Ok ;) quizás te entendí mal lo de una linea. En fin, yo creo que deberías mostrar un ejemplo pequeño (por ejemplo hacer `dput(head(tabla1)); dput(head(tabla2))` para que la comunidad entienda un poco más del problema y pueda trabajar con datos que se parezcan a los tuyos. Por último en lugar de iterar sobre indicides (`i in 1:8`) puedes iterar sobre un vector `for(var in names(tabla1))`, ejemplo ```mtcars1 <- mtcars
mtcars2 <- mtcars
mtcars2[] <- NA

for(var in names(mtcars1)) {
  
  mtcars2[[var]] <- mtcars1[[var]] * 100
  
}``` (copiar y pegar codigo y corregir los saltos de lineas)

Comment: @jbkunst 
Estoy trabajando con datos censales de mi país, por lo tanto, las tablas son bastante grandes.
La `tabla1` contiene la cantidad de personas por barrio y por franja etaria (en las filas están los barrios y en las columnas las diferentes franjas etarias)
La `tabla2` contiene la cantidad de personas por barrio y franja etaria, que realizan determinada actividad (es decir, tiene las mismas filas y columnas que la `tabla1`, pero en vez de indicar el número total de habitantes de esa franja et. por barrio, indica solo las personas que realizan esa determinada actividad)

Comment: Lo que quiero hacer es transformar la `tabla2` en una tabla que me muestre el procentaje de personas por barrio y por franja etaria que realizan la actividad en cuestión. 
Por eso multiplico cada variable (franjas etarias) por 100 y las divido entre el total de personas que hay de esa franja etaria

Comment: @jbkunst 
te pido disculpas por mi (casi) total ignorancia... Pero no me queda claro como sería lo de iterar sobre un vector.
te agradezco una vez mas por tu tiempo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para todos los que se han interesado en el problema que he planteado, quisiera comentarles que, a pesar de no haber conseguido una respuesta a mi inquitud, he encontrado una solución muy simple que me permite continuar avanzando.
Simplemente he puesto:

```
tabla1 * 100 / tabla2
```

y he comprobado que se hizo la operación para cada elemento de la `tabla 1` con su correspondiente en la `tabla2`.

Entiendo que esto lo pude hacer porque `tabla1` y `tabla2` tienen iguales dimensiones. Aun me gustaría saber cómo solucionarlo en caso de que no las tuvieran.

saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes obtener el resultado esperado usando la familia de funciones `apply` de R, específicamente, `lapply`.

Podemos transformar tu loop `for` a una llamada a `lapply`:

```
  lapply(names(tabla1), function(i){
    tabla1[i] * 100 / tabla2[i]
  })
```

Lo que estamos haciendo en este caso es similar a un `for`. Estamos aplicando una función anónima por cada elemento `i` en los nombres de variable en tabla 1 y como resultado obtendremos una lista.

Podemos usar después `as.data.frame()` si deseamos convertirlo a esta clase de objeto.

Este método tiene un par de ventajas.

La primera es que no importa si tabla2 tiene más o menos columnas que tabla1, tienen diferente nombre o están en un orden distinto, únicamente se realizaran operaciones con las columnas que tengan exactamente el mismo nombre en ambas tablas, las demás no serán tocadas.

La segunda ventaja es que esta es una función pura, en el sentido de que no realiza cambios en tus objetos tabla1 y tabla2. Obtendras como resultado una lista nueva que podrás guardar como un objeto distinto, anexar a alguna tabla existe o realizar las operaciones que desees en ella, sin que esto cambie nunca el contenido de tabla1 y tabla2.

Esto es conveniente, porque previene el riesgo de hagas modificaciones irreversibles o difíciles de rastrear en tus datos originales.

Y para complementar.

**¿Cuál es la diferencia entre `[]`, `[[]]` y `$`?**

Para entender la diferencia entre estas tres formas de hacer subconjuntos de R, conviene intentar usar cada una. Por ejemplo, con el conjunto de datos `iris`. He puesto como comentario el resultado que devuelven.

```
class(iris)
# [1] "data.frame"
class(iris$Species)
# [1] "factor"
class(iris["Species"])
# [1] "data.frame"
class(iris[["Species"]])
# [1] "factor"
```

Usar `[]` siempre nos devuelve un objeto de la misma clase que aquel del que estamos sacando un subconjunto. En este caso, iris es `data.frame` así que nos da un `data.frame`.

Usar `[[]]` y `$` nos devuelve un objeto que no siempre tiene la misma clase que aquel del que estamos sacando un subconjunto.

¿Qué clase de objeto? Esto depende de las clase y estructura del objeto original. En general, si usamos `[[]]` o `$` en un `data.frame`, obtenemos un vector atómico con una clase igual a la clase de datos que contiene (numérico, factor, cadena, entero, etc.).

La diferencia entre `[[]]` y `$` es que los corchetes pueden recibir índices numéricos como argumentos y que el signo de dolar sólo funciona para objetos con elementos con nombres.

La forma de subconjunto que empleemos depende, entonces, de la clase de objeto que necesitamos y el tipo de operaciones que deseamos realizar.

Comment: Gracias @Juan !!! Agradezco mucho tu tiempo y la prolijidad de tu explicación tan detallada. Me ha servido mucho las diferencias entre `[ ]`, `[[ ]]` y `$`. La sugerencia con la función `lapply`, no me ha dado errores pero lamentablemente tampoco me ha funcionado. Me devuelve `NULL` (una lista sin elementos). Gracias de todos modos y perdón por la tardanza en mi respuesta. Abajo añado un comentario de la solución que encontré (recién en el día de ayer) no a mi pregunta pero sí para "salir del paso"